# How long you can store a file in StorageItemAccessList?

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps

Apparently I cant use documents library capability in my C# Winstore app. So I am thinking of using file picker and StorageItemAccessList to cache access to the file in questions.

How this access list being maintained? I need to know **how long** an app can access a file stored in this list? **is there an expiration time for this list?**

what will happen **if the application is reinstalled** (new version installed or the same app was just uninstalled and then installed again)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two flavors of `StorageItemAccessList` available: [`FutureAccessList`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.accesscache.storageapplicationpermissions.futureaccesslist.aspx) and [`MostRecentlyUsedList`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.accesscache.storageapplicationpermissions.mostrecentlyusedlist.aspx).

`FutureAccessList` can store up to 1000 items (files or folders). Once you fill it up you need to remove existing items before adding new ones. I couldn't find any documentation on expiration time for it. Based on that and the quote [`your app maintains access to the item even if the user does not return to it frequently`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh972603.aspx#Preserving_access_to_files_and_folders_beyond_the_25-item_limit) I suppose items stay in the list permanently.

`MostRecentlyUsedList` can hold only 25 items (files or folders). Once it fills up, the oldest one is removed from the list when you add a new one. Again there should be no expiration time.

Installing a new version doesn't affect any of the lists. They remain unchanged. On the other hand when the app is uninstalled, both lists are lost just like any other locally stored data (exceptions are `RoamingSettings` and `RoamingFolder`).

Also keep in mind that you need a token to access files in both lists which you need to have stored elsewhere.